# How to get Mongodb Database collections data using asyn await in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

`

```
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const client = new MongoClient(url);
const database = 'youtube';

async function getData(){
    let result = await client.connect();
    let db = await result.db(database);
    console.log(db);
}
getData();
```

`

my 'db' variable not return any value in my console and my code not workin after using await client.connect()

Answer (score 0):

create a **utils** folder and create a file **mongodb.js** to use mongodb connection

**utils/mongodb.js**

```
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');

const [ MONGODB_URI, MONGODB_DB ] = [
  'mongodb://localhost:27017',
  'youtube'
]
console.log(`MONGODB_URI = ${MONGODB_URI }, MONGODB_DB = ${MONGODB_DB}`)

if (!MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error(
    'Please define the MONGODB_URI environment variable inside .env.local'
  )
}

if (!MONGODB_DB) {
  throw new Error(
    'Please define the MONGODB_DB environment variable inside .env.local'
  )
}

/**
 * Global is used here to maintain a cached connection across hot reloads
 * in development. This prevents connections growing exponentially
 * during API Route usage.
 */
let cached = global.mongo

if (!cached) {
  cached = global.mongo = { conn: null, promise: null }
}

module.exports = connectToDatabase=async ()=>{
  if (cached.conn) {
    return cached.conn
  }

  if (!cached.promise) {
    const opts = {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    }

    cached.promise = MongoClient.connect(MONGODB_URI, opts).then((client) => {
      return {
        client,
        db: client.db(MONGODB_DB),
      }
    })
  }
  cached.conn = await cached.promise
  return cached.conn
}
```

now use this file when you want to fetch data from database

```
var connectToDatabase =  require('./utils/mongodb');

app.get('/fetch-data',async (req,res)=>{
        const {db}= await connectToDatabase();
        const data = await db.collection('YourCollectionNameHere').find({}).toArray();
        return res.status(200).json(data);
});
```

Comment: No Sir, This code is not working.

Comment: @RajeevKumar , replace `YourCollectionNameHere` with your collection name  and`console.log(data)`